# How do you call a driver function from a user space program (assuming you have properly registered the driver)

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, system-calls

I suppose my question must seem hopelessly amateur, but I only started using linux seriously recently, and I cannot find a clear answer to this, rather simple question. I also have some additional questions, at the bottom of this post.

I want to know how to call a driver-specific implementation of a function from a user-space program (using the appropriate system call). I'm looking for the appropriate line of code. I can assume I have a major and minor number assigned to the driver, and that /dev and other directories have the appropriate files in them. I imagine the desired code would look something like:

```
system_call(major number, minor number, function ID, parameters, more parameters);
```

For reference, here is my driver init() code, copied more or less word-for-word from the Madieu book (LDD3):

```
static int __init my_init(void)
{
int i;
dev_t curr_dev;

/*Kernel EEP_NBANK devices*/
alloc_chrdev_region(&dev_num, 0, number_of_lanes, DEVICE_NAME);
/*Create device class*/
driver_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, DEVICE_CLASS);
/*this loop is sort of overkill, but you could change NUMBER_OF_DEVICES
so I'll use the loop just in case someone meddles with my source*/
for(i=0;i<number_of_lanes;i++){
    cdev_init(&driver_cdev[i], &driver_fops);
    driver_cdev[i].owner = THIS_MODULE;
    curr_dev = MKDEV(MAJOR(dev_num), MINOR(dev_num)+i);
    cdev_add(&driver_cdev[i], curr_dev, 1);
    device_create(  driver_class,
            NULL,
            curr_dev,
            NULL,
            DEVICE_NAME "%d",i);
}
return 0;
}
```

AS you can see, I've done the 4 steps necessary to access the program, at least according to those books. You can assume I've implemented the file_operations struct and the cdev structs, and so forth, correctly. You can also assume I have implemented a form the read or write function, which have prototypes:

```
ssize_t (*write)(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
```

Read is identical, but has (*read) instead of (*write). So, how do I get the correct values for *filp (is it implicit and the kernel does the work for me), *buf (passed from user space, I assume), count (passed from user space, I assume), and *pos (passed, again, from user space, I assume), and how do I call these functions from user space for a particular driver?

Hopefully this question is adequately clear, but if clarification is needed, I'll be around for the next few, plague-ridden, days. Thank you.

Comment: For read and write the higher levels of the kernel will do all the work for you for setting up the parameters. You call them from user space by first calling "open" on the device, and then calling "read", "write" and "lseek" in user space. I think the thing you are missing is that the point of the kernel is to abstract away the differences between writing to a terminal, a disk drive or a tape drive, you just do a "write". The kernel finds the correct function in the correct device driver and calls it from the upper level `write` code.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand you correctly, I'd basically call open on the /dev representation of the device, and then I just call read/write/etc by whatever name I've given them in the device? 

For example, 

struct file_operations{[...], .read = mydevice_read, [...]};

So then the user space code would look something like:

open(/dev_representation_of_Device);

mydevice_read(parameters);

Comment: No, your code looks like `fd=open("/dev/mydevice","r"); read(fd,buffer,6);` - the **only** thing that makes this your device rather than the terminal is the string parameter to the open call being "/dev/mydevice" rather than "/dev/tty".

Comment: Okay, thank you. That makes perfect sense and I see how it's implemented now.